# Is it possible to open Date & Time settings from iOS app in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a React Native app built with Expo. The app requires that user should have `Date & Time` set as `Set Automatically`.

1. Is there a way to fetch/check the current settings. Based on this, I want to show user a modal and ask them to change the settings.
2. On the modal, I want to have a button, and onPress of that button, I want to open the `Date & Time` settings for the user. Is there a built in way with React Native or some plugin that allows me to do this?

Currently the app is only on iOS, so I am not concerned about android implementations.

Comment: 1. No and 2. No. You cannot trust time on the device. If you need to know an accurate time you have to bet it from a server on the internet, for example.

Comment: Is this a limitation from React Native/Expo or this is in general not permitted with iOS? If there is a link to documentation that mentions this, can you please let me know?

Comment: The only preferences you can open on iOS is your own application's preferences.  Attempting to open any other preferences screen is considered private API use and will be rejected during app review.  This is nothing to do with the development language/environment

Comment: Guys @VivekVDwivedi, did anyone find solution for this. I tried using react-native-device-info, react-native-system-setting Nothing is working fine with these packages